# serialize a LazyDynaList of DynaBean using Jackson JAXRS provider

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using Jackson JAXRS JSON provider in my JEE application.

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.7.3'
```

I need to send a `List<?>` where each `?` is a `DynaBean` instance.

I.e:

```
public List<?> findXXX() {
    DynaClass dynaClass = new BasicDynaClass("Car", null, new DynaProperty[]{
        new DynaProperty("wheels", Long.TYPE),
        new DynaProperty("doors", Long.TYPE)}
    }
    );

    try {
        DynaBean car = dynaClass.newInstance();
        car.set("wheels", 4);
        car.set("doors", 2);
    }
    // ...

    List<DynaBean> cars = new LazyDynaList(dynaClass);
    cars.add(car);

    return cars;
}
```

When I send this `List<?>`:

```
public class SearchEndpoint implements ISearchEndpoint 
{

    @Inject protected SearchService searchService;

    @Override
    public Response search(String lqlSentence)
    {
        return Response.ok().entity(
            this.searchService.findXXX()
        ).build();
    }
}
```

After having built the response, jackson serializes this context as:

```
[
    {
        "dynaClass":{
            "dynaBeanClass":"org.apache.commons.beanutils.LazyDynaBean",
            "name":"org.apache.commons.beanutils.LazyDynaClass",
            "restricted":false,
            "returnNull":false,
            "dynaProperties":[
                {
                    "name":"wheels",
                    "type":"java.lang.Long",
                    "mapped":false,
                    "indexed":false
                },
                {
                    "name":"doors",
                    "type":"java.lang.Long",
                    "mapped":false,
                    "indexed":false
                }
            ]
        },
        "map":{
            "wheels": 4,
            "doors": 2
        }
    }
]
```

I'd like to send only:

```
[
    {
        "wheels": 4,
        "doors": 2
    }
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to create your own custom JSON serializer for your DynaClass?

Your custom serializer would look like this would something like this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;

public class DynaSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DynaClass> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(DynaClass dyna, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeObject(dyna.getMap());
        jgen.writeEndObject();

    }

}
```

And then in your DynaClass you will tell Jackson that you are using your own custom serializer.

```
@JsonSerialize(using=DynaSerializer.class)
public class DynaClass{
//Your class definition
}
```

And then to get your JSON string ...

```
String jsonStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new DynaClass());
```

And for more solutions check at this link it is super helpful.
http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: Above solution worked with just an amend, if dynaclass is a child of another class, then you don't want to do  jgen.writeStartObject()  and  jgen.writeEndObject();. you need to comment those lines